# Drawing Lines between 2 Panels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have been trying to get the GUI for my Java code to draw a line between two different colored panels. However, despite everything compiling alright, nothing happens. I have tried setting the line to a default thickness of 2 and color of black; incase it was invisible. I have tried adding it to the my_Frame constructor incase the line was simply not being added to the GUI. I believe I am misunderstanding something about Graphics2D, but I am not sure what.

Any idea or suggestions on what I can do to fix this?

````
    int x;
    int y;
    Graphics2D line;
    static float THICKNESS = 2;
    final static BasicStroke SOLID_STROKE = new BasicStroke(THICKNESS);

    my_Frame(){

        /**Frame Format*****************************************/
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(700,700);

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
  

        /**PANELS*****************************************/
        
        JPanel Cypanel = new JPanel();
        Cypanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        Cypanel.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 150);
        this.add(Cypanel);
        handleDrag(Cypanel);

        JPanel Grepanel = new JPanel();
        Grepanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        Grepanel.setBounds(150, 0, 150, 150);
        this.add(Grepanel);
        handleDrag(Grepanel);

        JPanel Redpanel = new JPanel();
        Redpanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        Redpanel.setBounds(500, 350, 150, 150);
        this.add(Redpanel);
        handleDrag(Redpanel);

        this.draw(line, Cypanel, Redpanel);
    }

    /***********************************************************************************
    * Allows the Panels to be draged around by the mouse
    ***********************************************************************************/
    public void handleDrag(final JPanel panel){
        
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
                x = me.getX();
                y = me.getY();
            }
        });
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                me.translatePoint(me.getComponent().getLocation().x-x, me.getComponent().getLocation().y-y);
                panel.setLocation(me.getX(), me.getY());
            }
        });
    }

    /***********************************************************************************
    * Draws a line between the two given panels
    ***********************************************************************************/
    public void draw (Graphics g, final JPanel scr, final JPanel des) {
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setStroke(SOLID_STROKE);
        g2d.drawLine(scr.getX(), scr.getY(), des.getX(), des.getY());
    }
    
} ```
````

Comment: Each JPanel has a separate Graphics instance.  You cannot draw anything that crosses from one JPanel to another.  You create one drawing JPanel and draw everything on the one and only drawing JPanel.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc *You cannot draw anything that crosses from one JPanel to another* - You do the drawing on the parent panel

Answer (score 0):

Lots of basics to learn first:

1. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.
2. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible
3. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` in the parent panel.

Start with the working example from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to simply draw a line with hard coded values.

Then add your two panels to that custom painted panel.

Finally add your logic to dynamically add the line to the panel. Hint to do custom painting of multiple lines you should keep an ArrayList of the lines you want to draw and then just iterate through the ArrayList in the paintComponent(..) method. See the `Draw on Component`example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).